# Strange results with Reachability

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm doing the OS X app to control my Arduino-robot. I have to check the reachability of two IP addresses of my robot: IP-camera and Arduino WiFi Shield.

I'm new in Xcode. I'm working with Xcode 5.1.1. under OS X 10.9.2. I want to do a very simple Mac app to check the reachability of the specific IP-address.
After reading several sources (including Apple and StackOverflow) I arrived to the code:

```
//  AppDelegate.m
//  MyCheckReachability
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { }

- (IBAction)check:(id)sender
{   NSString *ipAddr = [_getURL stringValue];     // this is just an IP-address from UI textField

SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, [ipAddr UTF8String]);
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags);

BOOL isReachable = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) != 0);
BOOL needsConnection = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired) != 0);
NSLog(@"%d  %d", isReachable, needsConnection);

if(isReachable && !needsConnection)
{ NSLog (@"… %@ - reachable", ipAddr); } else {NSLog (@"… %@ - NOT REACHABLE", ipAddr);}

CFRelease(reachabilityRef);
}
@end
```

I tried to test MyCheckReachability app with different IP addresses. I have an IP Scanner app which shows me all the IPs connected to my network.
Here is a result of my tests from the console:

1  0
 … 192.168.0.86 - reachable *(this IP exists)*

1  0
 … 192.168.0.87 - reachable *(this IP doesn't exist)*

1  0
 … 192.168.0.99 - reachable *(this IP doesn't exist)*

Surprisingly (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) is always =1 for **both existing and missing IP addresses.**
How can I judge on an reachability of IP address to communicate with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. The Reachability API just tells you if you have an interface/route that could reach the given destination. It does not actually try to contact the destination and communicate with it.

Per the [SCNetworkReachability documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html):

> Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host.

If you are trying to verify the ability to connect to a remote host, you will have to actually attempt a connection to it.